# How to set custom database keys?

Tags: database, sqlite

I am designing a database structure (SQLite on Android) that will consist of two tables, Containers(table 1) and Object/Container Data(table 2).

Table 1 will contain a key for the containers data and a list of keys for the containers/objects within.
Table 2 will contain the data for the object/container: title, description, category, pictures, etc.

With this design I will be able to go to a container, get its data (title, image) and get a list of items it holds, in order, then search for each items data(image, possibly title). Then the user could click on an item and if it is an object go to its data, or if it is a container, repeat this process.

How can I set the ID's for each table so that I can know which table an ID belongs to. For example, if an ID is even it points to table 1, if its odd, it points to table 2.

I think I may have just found an answer that seems rather obvious now... I just have to test it out. Basically you can just set a custom ID by setting the ID to what you want when you create the row.

```
INSERT INTO test1(rowid, a, b) VALUES(123, 5, 'hello');
```

I got that from http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html (Wish I would have seen it two days ago :)) And now I have to go, so I'll post back if this works when I get a chance.

I guess my only concern now (if it works) is does it create empty rows between the ID's you don't use, wasting space?

I've also considered just having two separate lists, but the order is important, so this would require another list to track the order of the objects, so I am wondering if key manipulation is possible.

Comment: Hello Z30Dragon and welcome to StackOverflow. I guess you should edit your question to add some sample structure so that people could look at it and spot the problem.

Comment: Hello, you can do this (using your own Id for insert) and it will not waste any space. However I recommend you to reconsider your general design. For example if I understand you correctly at the moment you are storing a list of keys in table 1. Does this mean you store all the ids in one column (comma separated or something similar?). This will lead to bad performance and is considered best practice. This should be in a third table if every object can belong to multiple containers or in the object table if every object belongs to exactly one container.

Comment: @aKzenT I think I am beginning to understand more about how databases work(thank you for that :)) If I do understand correctly, I should be able to use 1 table for data (title, description, etc.), and one table for location (container key, item key) then I can search through the location table for every object with correct container key, get item keys, search to get item data. correct? Only, how would I track the order of the items in each container? With my original idea, the order was kept in the list, now it would be lost entirely. Also, I updated question with how I would process the data.

Comment: Correctly. This is exactly what you should do. But only if there is a m to n mapping between container and item. You have to ask the question: Can one item be in more than one container at the same time? If not then instead of having a separate table you should add a column "ParentContainer" to your item table.

Comment: For the order: If the order depends on some property like the Name, etc. you can just tell SQLite to order the items by this property. If the order can be set by the user, then you can add another column "SortIndex" and use this for ordering.

Comment: @aKzenT Yeah, sorry, I missed adding that, yes, each item can be in more than one place, needing the other table for locations is what I was trying to avoid because I thought it would take a lot more to look up each item, but now I know a bit more about databases. Thank you for helping me with all of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If container and objects have common properties, then you could make a base table (Item) which contains the common properties and your Container and Object tables which contain only the extra data (inheritance).

This is known as a Table-per-Type hierachy (TPT). More information on [1] and [2].

Your containers can then link to Items using a simple foreign key, because independent of whether it's a container or an object it will have an entry there.

Now if you want to have only the objects you select all items from the container and do an INNER JOIN with your object table. Like this you will only get the objects and not the containers. If you only want the containers you do the join with the container table. If you want both containers and objects and need all extra data (that is not in the Item base table) you can do a LEFT OUTER JOIN with the object table and then a LEFT OUTER JOIN with the container table.

References:

[1] http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server

[2] http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/table-per-type-vs-table-per-hierarchy-inheritance.html

Comment: Thank you for the information aKzenT, but that's not what I'm trying to do, I have updated my question to be a bit more informative.

Comment: I know it doesn't answer directly your question, but I still recommend to consider my approach because it is a better database design in my opinion and you won't have a problem finding out if an Id belongs to table1 or table2.